# magento Deployment FTP Error. Invalid login credentials

Tags: magento-1.7

While we are saving the FTP details from Magento connect manager under setting tab, it gives the Deployment FTP Error. Invalid login credentials.

If we give invalid ftp details, it still gives the same error.

What will be the reason for this issue? Please give your valuable feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: do you want to install extension immediately ?

Comment: i want to update the existing module

Comment: if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [here](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files.

Let me know if you find any problems in this.

Comment: Yes, i know.. but i need to update through magneto connect manager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409798/magento-connect-ftp-settings

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue...

once again uploaded same version of downloader files contents to downloader folder.. the problem is solved..